# write access for kernel into a readonly segment

Tags: linux, operating-system, kernel

Until now I thought the kernel has the permissions to write in readonly segments. But this code has brought a lot of questions

```
int main() {
    char *x = "Hello World";
    int status = pipe((int*)x);
    perror("Error");    
}
```

The output of the code is

> `Error : Bad Address`

What my argument is, "*Since the `pipe` function executes in kernel mode the `ro` segment must be writable by kernel*". Which doesn't seem to be the case here. Now my questions are

> 1. How kernel protects the memory segments which are readonly?
> 2. Or am I assuming wrong about the kernel's capabilities?

Comment: There's a difference between being able to modify constraints and being able to violate them.

Comment: `How kernel protects the memory segments which are readonly? ` when you attempt to write to readonly region, you are unable as the address is being translated from virtual to physical, kernel will see in the page tables that there's no write permission in that address and will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Much like the user space, the kernel's address space is subject to whether a particular virtual address (also called a logical address) is mapped as readable, writable and executable. Unlike the user space though, the kernel has the free rein to map a group of virtual addresses with a page and change the page permission attributes. However, just because the kernel has the ability to map a page as writeable, does not mean the address stored in char*x was paged in the kernel's address space as writable, or even paged at all, at the time of the pipe call.

The way the kernel protects regions of memory is with a piece of hardware called a memory management unit (MMU). The MMU is what performs the mapping of virtual to physical addresses and enforces permissions in those regions. The kernel is more or less given free rein to configure the MMU. Unlike kernel space, user space code should be unable to access the MMU. Since the user space can not access the MMU, it can not change the page table's mappings or the permission attributes of a page. This effectively means that user space has to use the address space mapping and the permissions set by the kernel.

Comment: It means the kernel cannot to whatever with the user process's address space. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand where the "kernel can write to ro pages" assertion comes from. If the kernel wants to it can *remap* memory however it sees fit of course, but why would it do that for this case?

I presume you are running on x86. On this arch the kernel splits the address space into 2 parts (user/kernel). When you switch to the kernel, userspace is still mapped So in particular when the kernel wants tries to write to the provided address, it hits the same mapping your userspace process would. Since the mapping does not allow write access, the operation fails.

For the sake of argument let's say this would not hold true. That is, whatever read-only mapping is in userspace, the kernel will write to it anyway and that will work. Well, that would be an instant security problem - consider a file you can only read/exec, like the glibc. it is mapped read-only/exec. And now you make the kernel write to area, effectively changing the file for everyone. So why not in particular do read(evilfd, address_of_libc, sizeo_of_libc); and bam, you just managed to overwrite the entire lib with data of your choice.